# Spring Boot CachingConnection factory to connect to IBM MQ

Tags: spring-boot, spring-jms

I am using spring boot latest version 3.0.1 with camel and required to do IBM MQ connection to read messages.  STS showing below error.

> ERROR The method setTargetConnectionFactory(ConnectionFactory) from the type       SingleConnectionFactory refers to the missing type ConnectionFactory

Code:

```java
public CachingConnectionFactory createCrewcachingConnectionFactory() {
    CachingConnectionFactory factory = new CachingConnectionFactory();
    factory.setSessionCacheSize(10);
    factory.setTargetConnectionFactory(connectionFactory1());
    return factory;
}

public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory1() {
    MQQueueConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setHostName("MQ Host name");
        connectionFactory.setPort("MQ port");
        connectionFactory.setChannel("MQ Channel");
        connectionFactory.setTransportType(WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
    return connectionFactory;
}
```

POM Dependencies:

```xml
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <relativePath></relativePath>
</parent>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-spring-boot</artifactId>
    <version>3.19.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.19.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-jms</artifactId>
    <version>3.19.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hi . Just checking to see if you got resolution to the above issue.

Answer (score 0):

You will need the JMS API.  Something like:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.jms/javax.jms-api -->
<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
   <artifactId>javax.jms-api</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```